# how to put custom layer above Marker layer in mapbox-gl-js

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

Is there any way to put(a higher z-index) the below line (Mapbox layer) above This HTML marker(In my case chart)? If not, what is the alternative?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, HTML elements exist in the layer above the Mapbox GL JS canvas.

You could create two Mapbox GL JS elements, keep them in sync (movement-wise), with the top one containing just the line layer, with no background.

Comment: Thanks, @Steve, Are there any examples related to this approach? If yes, please share with us.

Comment: No public ones that I can think of immediately. I have used a technique like this in the past, for slightly different reasons. But synchronising the two maps is pretty easy using `mapOne.on('move', () => mapTwo.fitBounds(mapOne.getBounds()))`